# Workday - Direct Deposit API

Tags: workday-api

Does anyone know workday's SOAP API endpoint that allows to retrieve/set direct deposit information for an employee ?

I tried looking through the directory below but  couldn't find any relevant endpoint

https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/operations/index.html

Any assistance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you haven't found it yet, you are probably looking for Payment Elections, specifically [Get Payment Election Enrollments](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Cash_Management/v37.1/Get_Payment_Election_Enrollments.html) and [Submit Payment Election Enrollment](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Cash_Management/v37.1/Submit_Payment_Election_Enrollment.html)